# Python - Selenium Webdriverwait NoSuchElementException does not get caught by except

Tags: selenium, exception, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

So I have literally tried everything at this point.
I am getting the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9dRd.png)
The code that is causing the error is the below.
I have tried three difference excepts at this point, TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException and just a normal Exception, but neither works. If I uncomment the "raise NoSuchElementException" inside the try, it catches the error correctly, but not when it's the WebDriverWait that causes it?

Can someone please help :)

```
    try:
        #raise NoSuchElementException
        WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_class_name("stream-preview__preview-image--loaded").is_displayed())
    except TimeoutException:
        print('NoSuchElementException:')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('NoSuchElementException')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Are you not confusing the standard library NoSuchElementException with the webdriver api one? At least in java `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` and `java.util.NoSuchElementException` are two unrelated things.

Comment: I am using "from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException" so the webdriver one

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.